# showing form containing interface as parameter to a constructor WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I am trying to show main window after successful login.I used interface as parameter to constructor in main window. Now when I try showing main window, I get an error because I cannot pass interface as parameter to main window.I saw many posts like mine but I thought it is quite different from them.

This is my main window constructor:

```
public Home_Page(IGetAllItemClass clas)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _allClass = clas;
        }
        IGetAllItemClass _allClass;
```

My code in login Window from where I need to show main form:

```
 Home_Page h = new Home_Page();
 h.ShowDialog();
```

My app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Cafe_WPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cafe_WPF"
             Startup="App_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="scroll_style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is my App.cs :

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            #region login_dependencies
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IGetIP, get_ip_address>();
            container.RegisterType<IUserDetails, get_user_details>();
          container.RegisterType<IgetBusinessDetailsFromPosId, get_business_info_from_pos>();
            #endregion
            #region home_page_dependencies
            var home = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IGetAllItemClass, get_all_item_class>();
            Home_Page hm = home.Resolve<Home_Page>();
            #endregion
            Login_Window lg = container.Resolve<Login_Window>();
            lg.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

This is my interface:

```
namespace Cafe_WPF.Interface
{
  public interface IGetAllItemClass
    {
        DataTable item_class(string business_info_id, string rvc_id);
    }
}
```

And my class service implementing interface is:

```
class get_all_item_class : IGetAllItemClass
{
    public DataTable item_class(string business_info_id, string rvc_id)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = //query
            return CafePOS.Library.DataAccessLayer.Instance.ExecuteQuery(sql);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use dependency injection.May be I am missing something. Can anyone help me on this ? I am stuck on this.

Comment: Are you using Prism?

Comment: @RandyLevy sir I am using Unity.I am conpletely new to WPF.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't mistake `var home = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IGetAllItemClass, get_all_item_class>();
            Home_Page hm = home.Resolve<Home_Page>();`? I mean you create `home` container and then try to resolve `Home_Page` using another container.
By the way, it's very strange that you use two different containers in your case

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria sir I am completely new on this stuff. Can you please tell me how should I do this??

Comment: Try to use only one `UnityContainer` from `var container = new UnityContainer();` and `var home = new UnityContainer();`. I suggest use the first and replace `Home_Page hm = home.Resolve<Home_Page>();` to `Home_Page hm = container.Resolve<Home_Page>();`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Sir I made changes as per your suggestion but I am facing problem **Home_Page h = new Home_Page();
 h.ShowDialog();**  as Home_Page has an interface as argument. How can I resolve that? Could you please help?

Comment: You should pass `IGetAllItemClass` to `HomePage` directly when you create a new object using `new` or use `contaner.Resolve` from code above, so `Unity` resolves  contructor's arguments for `HomePage` and pass they to it. `Home_Page h = container.Resolve<Home_Page>();`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Sir maybe I am irritating you,but as much as I understood, I should do: **Home_Page h = new Home_Page();
 h.ShowDialog();** .But if I did so then it means I made tight coupling which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the dependency with the constructor
`var home = new HomePage(myDependencyInterface);`
If you don't have that dependency instantiated within your login page then you have to resolve it with your Unity container first:
`var myDependencyInterface = container.Resolve<myDependencyInterface>();`

Also as asked in the comments of your question, are you using Prism?
Because if so you just need to use `NavigateAsync(nameof(HomePage));` and Unity will inject the dependency

Comment: That's not what I wanted sir.. Passing interface manually reduces my expectation of DI. Could you please sugget me in Unity but not in Prism??

Comment: First off Prism and Unity are complementary (you should look into it for MVVM DI practices). Second I'm not sure you really understand what I'm explaining. By having the container resolving de dependency and injecting it into your HomePage constructor IS Dependency Injection.

Comment: I understood your explanation sir .I meant home page will have interface as argument in Constructor.Whenever I need to show Home page ,I have to pass instance of interface in it.That becomes tight coupling I think.

Comment: Then just do container.`Resolve<HomePage>().Show()`?